# Необходимо автоматически генерировать файлы .doc с заменой данных

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, vba

На работе появилась нужда автоматизации создания служебных записок(.doc)

1. Имеется телеграм-бот, который присылает уведомление о завершении торговой процедуры со ссылкой на страницу закупки.
2. На странице закупки нужно взять несколько значений (номер, наименование, цена)
3. Заменить в файле .doc шаблонные значения на взятые со страницы и сохранить отдельный файл.

Прошу лишь подсказать возможные пути решения, алгоритмы действия.
Спасибо!

Comment: не понятно, в чем конкретно ваш вопрос. Ну вот у вас задача, вот вы сами расписали, что вам надо сделать. Какие проблемы?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не совсем шарю в данной теме. Суть вопроса в следующем: я не знаю какими методами это можно сделать. Каким образом взять данные со страницы в интернете, каким образом заменить строки в ворде и т.д.

Comment: Я в подобной ситуации пользовался XML документами Word (не те, которые `.docx`, а те, которые `.xml`). Открывал их как обычный текст и вставлял необходимые данные в соответствующие места.